# Nagios+NGiNX "Primary script unknown" Error

Tags: nginx, nagios, php-fpm, debian-squeeze

I'm trying to get Nagios setup on NGiNX using PHP-FPM.

I installed `fcgiwrap` and and I'm able to execute a Perl script from the `cgi-bin` folder, but when I try to access Nagios, I get the following error in the NGiNX error log:

```
2012/08/23 16:40:21 [error] 8319#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.1.1.1, server: my.server.tld, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "my.server.tld"
```

I got this same error using the default locations, so I copied everything to different folders in order to keep the original installation files in-tact.

`cp -R /usr/lib/cgi-bin/nagios3 /var/www/cgi-bin`

`cp -R /usr/share/nagios3/htdocs /var/www/html`

This is what I have set in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
server {

        listen   80;

        server_name  my.domain.tld;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/my.domain.tld.access.log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/my.domain.tld.error.log;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {
                root /var/www/html/;
                auth_basic "Restricted";
                auth_basic_user_file /etc/nagios3/.htpasswd-users;
        }

        # Pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass   localhost:9000;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        }

        # FastCGI Wrapper
        location /cgi-bin/ {
                gzip off;
                root  /var/www/;
                fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

}
```

This is what I have set in my `/etc/nagios3/cgi.cfg`

```
physical_html_path=/var/www/html
url_html_path=/
```

This is what I'm running, PHP wise:

```
PHP 5.3.16-1~dotdeb.0 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Aug 17 2012 22:03:18)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.2.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Suhosin v0.9.33, Copyright (c) 2007-2012, by SektionEins GmbH
```

Any ideas on what would cause this and/or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify [ErikA's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/420598/126074):

It is saying **"Primary script unknown"** because **NGiNX** does *not* support running **CGI** directly. A helper program *must* be installed to process the **CGI** files and return the output to **NGiNX**.

This is why I had installed `fcgiwrap`, which processes the **CGI** files and passes the output to **PHP-FPM**, which is then processed by **NGiNX**, *AFAIUI*.

Although I thought I had started the `init.d` script for `fcgiwrap`, I had not.

I was able to determine this by running `netstat -alnp | grep cgi`, which returned no output until I started the script; `/etc/init.d/fcgiwrap start`

After I started it, I ran `netstat -alnp | grep cgi` again, and got the following output:

```
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     18955    11251/fcgiwrap      /var/run/fcgiwrap.socket
```

Once the script was running, and **CGI** was working, I no longer received this error, and **Nagios** worked.

*Yay for migraines that attribute to cloudy thinking and stupid little mistakes!*

Answer (score 0):

Unless something drastic has changed in recent versions, Nagios is not a php application.

Comment: This is just for the web interface.

Comment: Right, unless you're using a third-party UI, the frontend is CGI, not PHP.

Comment: I guess I should clarify that I moved all the files from their default locations, including the cgi files. `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/nagios3` > `/var/www/cgi-bin` and `/usr/share/nagios3/htdocs` > `/var/www/html`. I couldn't get it working using the default locations, either, and got the same error, so I moved them to mess with it more without jacking up the original install files.

Comment: It's still not a php application. Take php our of the picture to reduce complexity and then see what you can get done.

Comment: I was super awesome and had forgotten to start the `fcgiwrap` `init.d` script...